# ActionMailer is splitting my mail by 72 columns, breaking image links in HTML mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby 186, Rails 2.3.4.

We're trying to send HTML emails with a logo at the top served from a web address, but the URL to the logo is being split by the mail system at 72 characters using `=\n`. The address is then coming out as `img src"http://something.com/folder/anotherfo=\nlder/image.png`, which when viewed in an email app is a broken link.

I found a reference to 72 columns in mail_helper.rb

```
def block_format(text)
  formatted = text.split(/\n\r\n/).collect { |paragraph| 
    Text::Format.new(
      :columns => 72, :first_indent => 2, :body_indent => 2, :text => paragraph
    ).format
  }.join("\n")

  # Make list points stand on their own line
  formatted.gsub!(/[ ]*([*]+) ([^*]*)/) { |s| "  #{$1} #{$2.strip}\n" }
  formatted.gsub!(/[ ]*([#]+) ([^#]*)/) { |s| "  #{$1} #{$2.strip}\n" }

  formatted
end
```

but that function doesn't seem to get hit at all, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was in the transfer encoding for the text/html part. Setting :transfer_encoding => "base64" solved the issue.